dataframe.rdd.getNumPartitions() not returning the same value as the number of partitions set when creating the Spark session
dataframe.rdd.getNumPartitions() not returning the value that is set to the Spark session when doing SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", value).getOrCreate().
This was working in the previous version of pyspark that I used 3.1.3 but now on 3.5.1 it is not working. Does anyone know what the issue is?
